# what does qtp stand for in solr logs

Tags: solr

In solr logs(solr.log) file there is an entry that starts with qtp[\d+]-[\d], something like qtp90248349499-123. What is that
Is it a thread dump, what does qtp stand for ? How can you find more about what that piece of data is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qtp` stands for `QueuedThreadPool` and is the internal thread pool used in Jetty - the application container that Solr uses. The number is the hash code of the object created, and isn't used for anything other than uniquely identifying the QueueThreadPool that's generating the log message.

You can [see the relevant code on GitHub](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/9706d70484863a014d3604e5e7cb4af40aa4cb1e/jetty-util/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.java#L68):

```
@ManagedObject("A thread pool")
public class QueuedThreadPool extends ContainerLifeCycle implements SizedThreadPool, Dumpable, TryExecutor
{
    .....
    private String _name = "qtp" + hashCode();
```

Comment: hi @MatsLindh , thanks for the clarification, appreciate your help.

Comment: Follow up question, I would like to know how many threads a solr process is using, I do the following , find the process id for solr process and use that process id, to find the treads as follows. ps huH -p processid, I do see bunch of threads, is that the right approach?

Comment: Hey @BabulReddy if you have another question, please ask another one :) Maybe abstract the question a bit. What do you want to get to work?